# Jasper Report: error executing SQL statement by Collection Parameter

Tags: postgresql, parameters, jasper-reports

I'm creating a report which's passing by collection parameter.
The parameter name as 'ids' and the class is java.util.Collection.

My query:

```
select  * from order_deliveryorder a 
left join order_deliveryorderline b on a.id = b.d_order_id
left join order_item c on c.id = b.product_id
left join order_orderline e on e.id = b.s_order_id
left join order_order f on e.order_id = f.id
left join order_itemsection g on g.id = f.section_id
left join order_location d on d.id = a.location_id
left join order_location h on h.id = a.from_location_id 
where a.id in ('2377900603251741014','2377900603251740997','2377900603251740967')
```

the query in jasper:

```
select  * from order_deliveryorder a 
left join order_deliveryorderline b on a.id = b.d_order_id
left join order_item c on c.id = b.product_id
left join order_orderline e on e.id = b.s_order_id
left join order_order f on e.order_id = f.id
left join order_itemsection g on g.id = f.section_id
left join order_location d on d.id = a.location_id
left join order_location h on h.id = a.from_location_id 
where $X{IN, a.id,  ids}
```

The value of parameter "ids" is ["2377900603251741014","2377900603251740997","2377900603251740967"]

In the End, had met the error executing sql statement.

Comment: 1) What error did you get? 2) Do you have `Collection<String>` or `Collection<Integer>`? 3) Did you try to debug?

Comment: i change another method to pass the parameter, just pass it as string "a.id in ('2377900603251741014','2377900603251740997','2377900603251740967')".

Reply 2: i only set it parameter as java.util.Collection.
Reply 3: is there any debug tools in jaspersoft@stuidio?